# append row or column in c++ when row and column values are user defined

Tags: c++, class, matrix, dynamic

i have written this code to execute following task using class when size of the matrix is decided at runtime that is i want create a rectangular matrix into a square matrix such that the column or row appended will have all elements as 1

```
5 4 5
2 3 1
```

to

```
5 4 5
2 3 1
1 1 1
```

```
class Array{
    int **p,r,c;
    public:
        void setsize();
        void read();
        void print();
        void createsqm();
};
void Array :: setsize()
{
    cout<<" Enter rows and cols "<<endl;
    cin>>r>>c;
    if(r>c)
    {
        p = new int *[r];
        for(int i =0; i<r; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new int [r];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        p = new int *[c];
        for(int i =0; i<c; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new int [c];
        }   
    }
}
void Array :: read()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cin>>p[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void Array :: createsqm()
{
    if (r>c)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=c; j<r; j++)
                p[i][j]=1;
        }   

    }
    else
    {   int i,j;
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            for(i=r; i<c;i++)
               p[i][j]=1;

        }   
    }   
}
```

i want to know where i am making a mistake

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would be a better idea than `int**` as you no longer have to manage your own memory. Even better would be a proper math library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Currently your class doesn't initialize any members on construction. You also need to implement a destructor, copy-assignment operator, copy constructor, and (if on C++11 or better) move-assignment operator, and move constructor. This is all before you even begin to implement the useful methods of the class. If you just use `std::vector` then this all becomes automatic!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:

> i want to know where i am making a mistake

There are several layers, where you do a mistake.

- Requirments:

You want to implement an array in C++, although everything (`std::array`, `std::vector` etc.) is available. Do not do that, except for academic purposes.

- Design

You do really use `new` and pointers (for owned memory) and plain C-Style arrays in C++. You should (must) not use `new`. And also, please never use pointers for ressources, like owned memory. Don't do it. Avoid using C-Style arrays. There is no need and they are error prone.

- Implementation

Hard errors:

createsqm will write out of bounds. It will corrupt the memory. Your array has an inital size and you are accessing rows or coulmns that are not existing.

You are not initializing your variables

You use memory that may not be allocated. There is no check

There are no boundary checks before accessing raw memory. Which will lead to a problem in your code.

- Others

Keep scoping tight. For example. Define loop varaible in the for statement and not above.

Name your variables so that anybody (for example you in 3 months) can understand the code.

Do not open the complete `std`-namespace

Follow some coding standard and indentation standard.